# doesn't switchClass work to add/remove class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
$('#searchBox input').focus(function(){
                            console.log(true);
                            $('nav').addClass('searching');

 });
 $('#searchBox input').blur(function(){
                            console.log(false)
                            $('nav').removeClass('searching');
});
```

this works fine: adds and removes 'searching' class to the nav element depending focus or blur.

i wanted to add some animation and instead of animating each element, wanted to try the switchClass

```
$('#searchBox input').focus(function(){
                            console.log(true);
                           // $('nav').addClass('searching');
                            $('nav').switchClass( 'no-existe',  "searching", 1000 );
                        });
                        $('#searchBox input').blur(function(){
                            console.log(false)
                            //$('nav').removeClass('searching');
                            $('nav').switchClass(  "searching",'no-existe', 1000 );
});
```

no-existe is a non existing class (figured out i needed to pass something in the remove/add parameter)
wich logs the true/false but doesn't alter nav's class

any idea why?

Comment: Which param in the class are you trying to animate?

Comment: i am trying to remove first (wich doesn't exist on focus) and animate to the second parameter classname

Comment: got ya , so I take it the seaching class gives the input a border or background color?

Comment: the search class: increases input's width, and hides all links. similar to the keydown effect on the search field on this website

Comment: Ok , you need to create another class with all of those reverted and switch from searching to that class.

Comment: Well, i created some styles from 'no-existe' and apply it on the html (by default) and the class is not switching either

Comment: It would probably be easier to use jquery animate (for the input box) and hide (for the links) methods .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[switchClass()](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/switchClass) probably checks to confirm that the selected element has class "no-existe" before it adds class "searching". I don't see anything in the docs to support the way you're calling it.

Answer (score 1):

SwitchClass is part of the jquery UI

See http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/switchClass

Are you importing the jQuery UI library ?